# ffmpeg "Stream specifier matches no streams", but it exists

Tags: ffmpeg

In ffmpeg, I have the following filter_complex:

```
color=c=Chartreuse:s=1920x1080:d=8640.059,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t];
[1:v] trim=start=114.149:end=124.149,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v0];
[t][v0]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,10)' [o0];
[2:v] trim=start=118.112:end=135.112,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v1];
[o0][v1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,27)' [o1];
[o0][o1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [vout]
```

But when I run the command with 3 inputs (the first one is an audio file), I get:

> Stream specifier 'o0' in filtergraph description
>   color=c=Chartreuse:s=1920x1080:d=8640.059,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t];
>   [1:v] trim=start=114.149:end=124.149,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v0];
>   [t][v0]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,10)' [o0]; [2:v]
>   trim=start=118.112:end=135.112,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v1];
>   [o0][v1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,27)' [o1];
>   [o0][o1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [vout]  matches no streams.

What am I doing wrong?

Using a git version from ~1 week ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future reference:

as specified, you cannot reuse an intermediate stream more than once so you have 2 options:

1. either save it, input the saved file and reuse it as many times you need in your filter;

> `ffmpeg -i file1 -i file2 -i savedStream -filter_complex "..."`

2. use the [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) filter and create as many outputs you need; default value for split is 2 outputs so:

> `[o0]split[split1][split2]`

would be your case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an intermediary stream, as produced by the color filter, cannot be reused more than once, so we have to use the split filter on it:

```
color=c=Chartreuse:s=1920x1080:d=8640.059,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t];
[t] split=2 [s0][s1];
[1:v] trim=start=114.149:end=125.149,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v0];
[s0][v0]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,11)' [o0];
[2:v] trim=start=115.629:end=123.629,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v1];
[s1][v1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,11,19)' [o1];
[o0][o1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [vout]
```

I couldn't find any explicit documentation on that limitation, altough I'm sure it exists somewhere.

Comment: Workaround is to generate it as an input stream alongside other file inputs: `-i file -i file -f lavfi -i "color=c=Chartreuse...` and then ingest it repeatedly like other files `[2:v]...`